# Creating a Qt install package with InnoSetup : missing images

Tags: qt, resources, qt-creator, inno-setup, qt-resource

I'm developing a Qt app in Qt Creator. I'm creating an install package via `InnoSetup`. And everything works OK except all the images are missing in the installed program (running it in Qt Creator works fine).

I'm using [The Qt Resource System](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html)

In my `.pro` file I have

```
RESOURCES += \
res/resources.qrc
```

If in my `resources.qrc` I have something like this:

```html
<RCC>
   <qresource prefix="/icons">
       <file>4000003.png</file>
       ...
   </qresource>
</RCC>
```

I access my images for example like this:

```
title->setIcon(QPixmap(":/icons/" + QString::number(id) + ".png"));
```

The structure of my directory is :

```
MyApp
 -sources files (i.e. `.cpp`, `.h`) 
 -res/
   -all the images
   -resources.qrc
build-release
 -release/
   - MyApp.exe
```

So should I have exactly the same struture in `InnoSetup`? Meaning I should have the `build-release\release` directory and the `MyApp\res` as well? Because I tried that and it didn't help.

Comment: And it's still not clear to me, what you ask for. You have to instruct Inno Setup to create the same directory structure on the target machine that works for you locally. So what is the structure that you need?

Comment: I created the same structure, but it didn't fix my problem. So I assumed the problem is on the Qt side and that maybe The Qt Resource System doesn't work as I would like it to work in this case.

Comment: So can you deploy your app manually, by copying the required files to another system?

Comment: No, it only works from within Qt Creator or when I deploy the exe created by Qt Creator in it's original place.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl please see the updated question.

Comment: If you cannot even deploy your application manually, then do not ask an Inno Setup question. First ask how to deploy an application created in Qt Creator. Your current question requires someone who has both Qt Creator and Inno Setup knowledge. You will have hard times finding anyone who knows both. Solve one problem at a time.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Sorry I didn't uderstand your question. Yes I can deploy my app on different systems.

Comment: You wrote "No, it only works from within Qt Creator"

Comment: Yes, I thought you were asking about whether the images are there.

Comment: If you use the Qt resource system correctly, then the images are all compiled into your `MyApp.exe`, and are also retrieved from there at run time. So we need more information to be able to help you, like how your project file looks like (are your correctly point to your resource file), and how you access your image resources in your application.

Comment: @E4z9 Thanks for answering! I updated the question. If you need any more information, let me know!

Comment: That looks fine to me. Does your InnoSetup install your application executable verbatim without fiddling around with it? Not sure how to check on Windows, but on mac/linux I'd start with comparing e.g. the checksum of the installed .exe vs the one from the build